# Mingw32-w64 GCC 4.9.2 regex bug, or me not knowing C++?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, gcc, scope

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char rs[] = R"((\s+)|([\r\n][\r\n]?))"; /* split on whitespace or newline */
    regex r(rs); // this regex declared like a local variable
    string s("foo  bar \t baz\nqux quux corge");

/* Part 1 */

    sregex_token_iterator
            first {begin(s), end(s), r, -1},
            last;
    vector<string> tokens1 {first, last};
    for(auto i : tokens1) {
        cout << i << ", ";
    }

/* Part 2 */

    cout << endl << endl << "inline:";
    //string regexstring(rs); // <<< uncomment for different behavior

    /* here, the regex is created inline */
    sregex_token_iterator
            first2 {begin(s), end(s), regex(rs), -1},
            last2;

    vector<string> tokens2 {first2, last2};

    for(auto i : tokens2) {
        cout << i << ", ";
    }
}
```

This has been driving me nuts for some time. This program bombs on my machine, it gets stuck in some loop when printing tokens from `tokens2` until it segfaults. If you uncomment the indicated line, the program runs. However, only `tokens1` contains the properly split tokens, and I fail to see where the difference is.

This is a simplified minimal example that reproduces the behavior on a machine with WinXP SP3, Code::Blocks and a newly downloaded from Sourceforge (today) Mingw64 GCC 4.9.2 for win32. I get the same behavior with the TDM-GCC-W32 build of GCC 4.9.2.

Clearly these must be 2 bugs right? Or do I *really* not understand C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`regex_token_iterator` is not meant to be called with a temporary `regex` object as you do in *part 2* as it does not store a copy of the `regex` instance. *Part 2* causes undefined behavior because the call results in an iterator that has already been invalidated due to the `regex` instance being destroyed at the end of the expression.

[C++14 fixes this problem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator) by adding `delete`d rvalue overloads that would've prevented your second example from compiling.